# Помогите с тире

Tags: пунктуация, тире

Стоит ли тут тире?

Как следствие - почувствовал себя неловко.

Comment: Раз Вы поставили, значит, стоИт.)) Другое дело, нужно ли оно. И почему в заголовке о запятых?!

Answer (score 2):

Как следствие - почувствовал себя неловко.

**Обособленный обстоятельственный оборот** "как следствие" со значением "в результате, в итоге".

Тире авторское, соответствует паузе в устной речи, что определяется структурой данного предложения. Чаще такие обороты **обособляется запятой**, но **иногда вообще не обособляются** (входят в основное сообщение).

Примеры

**И как следствие**, такое сокращение озона ведёт к охлаждению Земли, хотя сам озон тоже поддерживает тепличный эффект.

**Как следствие** ― 1 декабря 2001-го на учредительном съезде он был избран председателем Генсовета.

**Как следствие** сужаются кровеносные сосуды, питающие фолликулы, и не хватает гормонов, необходимых для роста волос.

Answer (score 0):

На сочинении в МГУ (или диктанте) тире в данном случае сочли бы дикостью. Или просто ошибкой. Авторские знаки препинания разрешают только классикам, а абитуре - нет. Поэтому только запятая. Как положено.